# Removing the [ ] and commas in brackets in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the commas and box brackets [ ] in the list. The program asks the user to enter in the number of values they want randomized within a range of their choosing then displays the results. Currently the program prints out as:

```
How many #s do you want? 10
Enter the lowest number to generate 1
Enter the highest number to generate 10
[1, 8, 6, 3, 6, 10, 4, 2, 10, 9]
```

but I need it to display as:

```
How many #s do you want? 10
Enter the lowest number to generate 1
Enter the highest number to generate 10
1 8 6 3 6 10 4 2 10 9
```

Maybe I'm going about it incorrectly? Thoughts?

```
import random

def main():
  numbers = int(input("How many #s do you want? "))
  numbers_2 = int(input("Enter the lowest number to generate "))
  numbers_3 = int(input("Enter the highest number to generate "))

  pop = make_list(numbers, numbers_2, numbers_3)
  print(pop)
  num_string = ""

  for i in sorted(pop):
    num_string += str(i) + " "
  return num_string

def make_list(numbers, numbers_2, numbers_3):
  num_list = []
  for numbers in range(numbers):
    num_list.append(random.randint(numbers_2, numbers_3))
  return num_list

main()
```

Comment: Your print happens before you convert them to a string (sorted by the way, which contradicts your example. Just print `num_string` before return?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `print(*pop)`.

When given several parameters (e.g., `print(1, 2, 3)`, the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) command will print them all out, converted to strings, separated by spaces.

With the `*`, your array `pop` is unpacked so that it forms the parameters for the `print` function.

By setting the `sep` parameter, you can even change the separator. For example, `print(*pop, sep=",")` would give `1,8,6,3,6,10,4,2,10,9`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the list, and so it is formatted appropriately in the output. To control the formatting, use `print` e.g.

```
print(' '.join(map(str,pop)))
```